# Stop properly SpringBoot jmsApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I want to stop properly a jms application,I have the following code, where from the listener i am calling shutdown method:

```
   public void initiateAppShutDown(int returnCode){
        SpringApplication.exit(context, ()-> returnCode);
   }
    
   public void shudDownApplication(){
        LOGGER.debug("Arret de l'application injecteur");
        initiateAppShutDown(0);
   }
```

i am performing the shutdown from method `onMessageReceived()` of the listener  , but i have the following warnings , that seems that messages are rejected from the listener:

```
Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483647 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry]
```

And the following :

DefaultMessageListenerContainer: Rejecting received message because of the listener container having been stopped in the meantime:

UPDATE

here is my counter declaration

```
// we increment the counter. incrementer nombre de messages traités
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

`incrementCounter()` Method increments `counter`

```
public void incrementCounter() {
    counter.getAndIncrement();
}

public int get() {
    return counter.get();
}
```

here is the method when the shutdown is called :

```
private void checkNumberMessagesProcessed() {
    if(this.get() == Integer.parseInt(nbrMaxMessages)){
        LOGGER.debug("fin de traitement reprise backout avec nombre de messages traites:  " + this.get());
        //close listeners
        //shutdown();
        //close application
        shudDownApplication();
    }
}
```

I still have messages treated even though i reached `nbrMaxMessages=1000` parametrised,and the application restarts automatically :here is the log:

```
2020-09-18 11:59:34,702 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-2] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : end  process  backout with number of treated messages :  1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,704 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-9] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304740080b5f1487913fe5270000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,705 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-5] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045f0080b5f08647b4ab6760000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,705 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-3] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304740080b5f116d7b4de1960000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,705 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-4] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304750080b5f136b3193b7690000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,708 DEBUG --- [pool-7-thread-1] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : Shutdown application injecteur backout
2020-09-18 11:59:34,709 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-4] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045f0080b5f14f4120ec5b60000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,709 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-3] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045f0080b5f14003c676edb0000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,711 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-5] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304750080b5f1394ecc8bc480000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,711 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-2] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045f0080b5f15042af6ac7b0000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,712 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-8] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045b0080b5f150c84093cf60000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,712 DEBUG --- [ackout-1-10] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045b0080b5f0887a7225de50000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,714 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-3] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304730080b5f1649ac4348a70000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,714 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-4] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304730080b5f14fffe80e4a10000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,716 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-5] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304740080b5f146dee9feec60000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,716 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-2] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045b0080b5f158b80eac21f0000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,718  INFO --- [pool-7-thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@53dbe163: startup date [Fri Sep 18 11:59:32 CEST 2020]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7a5ceedd
2020-09-18 11:59:34,719 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-3] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213045b0080b5f08b16224e18f0000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,720 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-4] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213047e0080b5f16b62be157e60000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,721 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-5] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 49585321304730080b5f15dd2ce0d2df0000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,721 DEBUG --- [Backout-1-2] g.c.s.b.c.GdrBackoutListener             : inject message 495853213047e0080b5f084d3a3b00260000000000000000 dans INTERNAL_QUEUE with number of messages to trate to 1000
2020-09-18 11:59:34,723  INFO --- [pool-7-thread-1] o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor        : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
```

Answer (score 1):

You're triggering a shutdown call in the same thread and it's like dead lock, your onMessage method is waiting for shutdown while JMS container is waiting for running task to be terminated and it gets eventually timedout.

To solve this issue, you can use a async executor that would trigger the shutdown, something like this.

```
@Component
public class MessageListener {
   ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
   @JmsListener(...)
   public void onShutdownMessage(Message message){
       // increase delay further if observer any issue, it will trigger shutdown call in 1 seconds
       executorService.schedule(() -> {shudDownApplication();}, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
}
```

Comment: i updated the post , i have errors and the listener and the applications does not stop properly

Comment: seems that thread Backout-1-2 stops process but threads Backout-1-9 , Backout-1-5, Backout-1-3, Backout-1-4 continue processing eventhough 1000 messages reached .
the thread pool pool-7-thread-1 stops application 
but we can ee that threads continue processing untill the thread pool pool-7-thread-1 stopping beans

Comment: @ArezkiMouaz what's the concurrency of this listener? Set this to 1, as this is only used for management purpose.

Comment: Each listener can have their concurrency, given this listener is used for management purpose, it should not execute ,more than one commands at the same,

Answer (score 0):

finally i solved the problem.

i had a cyclic dependency on my listener.

i tried to tell the listener to stop itself after  waiting  for all threads to finish their work.

that was not correct as an approach .so i created an error handler ,then i throw errors from the JmsListener . and the shutdown is managed throw a shutDownManager class.
in the shutDownManager i created a new thread where to stop the springApplication.
this approach works fine for a thread concurrency context. here is the code :

```
@Component
public class AppContextManager implements ApplicationContextAware {
       private static ApplicationContext _appCtx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx){
         _appCtx = ctx;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getAppContext(){
        return _appCtx;
    }

    public static void exit(Integer exitCode) {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(_appCtx,() -> exitCode));
    }

    }
```

and in error handler ,when u want to shutdown your application you catch exception thrown fro Jmslistener  ,you call this method

```
private void shutDown(){
//JmsListenerEndpointRegistry bean = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    executorService.execute(() -> {
        //bean.stop();
        appContext.exit(0);
    });

}
```

this allows you to shutDown silently your Listeners and the custom tread waits all the threads to finish execution